# Restrict certain elements or popups

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am implementing an ad-block system which hides any content which contain the following. This doesn't seem to be working, can anyone point out the error?

LifeSpanHandler.cs

````
public class LifeSpanHandler : ILifeSpanHandler
{
    bool ILifeSpanHandler.OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
    {
                   newBrowser = null;

        if (targetUrl.Contains("google-analytics") ||
            targetUrl.Contains("googletagmanager") || targetUrl.Contains("gstatic") ||
            targetUrl.Contains("myvisualiq") || targetUrl.Contains("quantserve") ||
            targetUrl.Contains("scorecardresearch")|| targetUrl.Contains("Advertisement"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    void ILifeSpanHandler.OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
    {

    }

    bool ILifeSpanHandler.DoClose(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
    {
        return false;
    }

    void ILifeSpanHandler.OnBeforeClose(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser){}```
````

Form1.cs

````
        public loader()
        {
            browser.LifeSpanHandler = new LifeSpanHandler();
            browser.Load("https://soundcloud.com/");
        }```
````

Comment: return true to cancel, return false to allow the default behaviour. As per the documentation http://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_ILifeSpanHandler_OnBeforePopup.htm

Comment: @amaitland I figured out but thanks.